# Rotation around a point

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, rotational-matrices

Can anyone help me with this please

I want to be able to rotate a 3D object around a stationary 3D object. Well there will be no movement involved as I just want to draw the objects at their locations once the game starts and then they will remain there for the remainder of the game.

Say for instance I have a object X that is stationary in 3D space. I then have 2 other objects, Y1 and Y2. Both of these objects are stationary as well and cant be moved. All 3 objects are on the same x and y axis. Lets say X is at (0,0,0) and Y1 is at (0,0,-50). I want to draw Y2 at a 45 degree angle from Y1 around the Y-axis but keep it the same distance from X.

Can anyone please suggest the best way of doing this please?
I have tried the following but that just rotates the object around its origin. So I guess I have to rotate it around the world origin? How is this done?

```
Matrix.CreateRotationY(Rotation)
```

Comment: I have tried a Quaternion rotation but I simply cannot get this to work. It draws the X model at the origin but whenever I rotate my camera around the screen to see if Y2 has rotated, it looks like there is a giant floating plane drawn to the screen and no matter how far away I try and zoom the camera to get a view of it it stays at the same place. So Im just wondering if there is a different approach that I can take cause I have hit a brick wall with Quaternions...

Comment: If you want the thing to rotate on the X,Y plane, that's a rotation about the Z axis. You need to call `CreateRotationZ`.

Comment: Oops no sorry that's my mistake maybe, I definitely want to be able to rotate it around the Y-axis. Ill edit the post now to mention that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but this is one method for rotate one object around another:

```
  Vector3 Origin;     // Stationary Object

  float Yaw, Pitch;   // Angles 

  float Distance;     

  Vector3 OrbitOffset = Vector3.UnitX * Distance;

  // Other approach that consider the initial pos of the object to rotate
  // Vector3 OrbitOffset = OrbitPos - Origin;       

  Matrix Rotation = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(Yaw, Pitch, 0);

  Vector3.Transform(ref OrbitOffset, ref Rotation, out OrbitOffset);

  Vector3 OrbitPos = Origin + OrbitOffset;  // Final position of the rotated object
```

Comment: At a quick glance this looks like what I want. Just to be clear, after the calculations are done, does Vector3 OrbitPos then become my Y2 objects new position? Also, no pitch is needed so I can set this to 0 in Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(Yaw, 0, 0)? Actually, come to think of it, does CreateFromYawPitchRoll() not simply rotate an object around its own axis? Not close to my dev machine at the moment to try out the algorithm

Comment: 1) Yes, it's a final pos.2) Of course. 3) this rotation matrix (or any) will rotate the object around the (0,0,0)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Blau, just on my way home now and Ill try it shortly. Thanks again for yor help

Answer (score 1):

if you dont need rotation about more than 2 angles at once, you can use basic Euler method.
see :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations

thats a mathematical approach tough... but it works.. 
Just if you want a rotation around multiple axes, you will have serious problems with gimbal lock

Comment: Thanks Ill have a look at this. Yeah simply want to rotate around the Y-axis so no need to worry about gimbal lock. All I need to do basically is set Y2 at the position and then I will use that position for other calculations.

Comment: @hansmoolman

To change the center of rotation, simply add the center's coordinates to base coordinates, do the rotation and subtract the center's coordinates